# Programmatically stop Azure Service Fabric service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have several services running in an ASF cluster. Is it possible to take pause/stop/restart a service in an ASF cluster across all nodes programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you cannot stop a 'service' in Service Fabric. You can only remove it. But you can start/stop, enable/disable nodes within the cluster.

There is a enhancement request in Azure feedback forums to have the service start/stop feature. Vote for it and wait for it to be implemented.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/13714473-ability-to-stop-disable-services-without-removing

Comment: is it still the case that we cannot stop services?